# Set ringtone to start from a specific point

Tags: nexus-5, ringtone

I recently got my Nexus 5 and I would like to know if there is any way that I can set a ringtone to start from a specific point from a track that I have on my phone.

Is there any way that can help me do that, considering that I don't want to cut the track to the point that I want my ringtone to start from?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think that can be done! Why don't you use several MP3 cutters to cut the song over to the appropriate place you like?

There is a load of song cutter apps available over the Play Store, as well as software also available for PCs. I have tried searching over the Play Store and got several apps names MP3 cutter which can help you out with cutting the ringtone to a specific point and then then you can set that as your ringtone.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create custom ringtones.

1. Through an Android app from the Play Store
2. Real player MP3 cutter which cuts the MP3 from the desired starting time (from where to start) and the end time as well (till where it should play)

Now for this-

> [...] considering that I don't want to cut the track to the point that I want my ringtone to start from?

is completely irrelevant because without specifying/cutting the start time, how will the audio file start to play as all the audio/video files start from 00:00?

The audio file cannot randomly start anywhere you like. It has to have a point where you need the song to start (00:00 till the end but not from 2:50 till the end).

**Ex**:- Suppose you have a Beethoven audio file in which you want the phone to ring from **4:00** till **4:35** i.e. 35 seconds then with the help of an MP3 cutter, you will set the starting point from **4:00 and ending point to 4:35** . After you have set the slider, then you need to cut that particular portion and it will be set as 00:00 to 00:35. This song will not replace the original Beethoven song but will add an extra song of just 35 secs as a ringtone.

Comment: Actually it's possible to include a start/end point in the meta tags of the audio file. For example iTunes can do this. But it isn't applicable in this case since the start/end points can't be defined as "ringtone-only", so it has the same effect as cutting the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but an important detail: I discovered that from a song length of 1:30 (90 seconds), Android seems to pick a fragment from the middle of the song instead of the beginning. So, if you cut your own ringtone and expect that it starts from the beginning, it must be less than 1:30 in length. 1:29 is fine.

(checked with a Galaxy S10)